# Show that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{[n+(-1)^n]^2}$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show that this series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{[n+(-1)^n]^2}$ converges??

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$0<\frac1{\left(n+(-1)^n\right)^2}\le\frac1{(n-1)^2}$$

Comment: Oh...comparison test!! Thanks...I was confused with the altenating term inside...

Comment: @eChung00: That’s right. The alternating term doesn’t really hurt, because its size is constant, while the denominator overall is increasing without bound. Thus, the effect of the alternation approaches $0$ as $n$ increases.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the terms when $n=2m$ and $n=2m+1$ and compare to $a_n=n^{-2}$.